# windows 7 monitor instantly resumes from power off

Tags: windows-7, display, power, blank-screen

It seems that some service or program is preventing my monitor from going into power save mode but I cannot find a way to dig down the cause.

Does anybody know a way to find out which event may be causing the problem?

***Background information:***
If I leave/lock my computer I want to **immediately** power off the monitor.
Stupid windows has no program for this so I use a third party utility.
I use Display.exe from Noel Danjou since 2005 and have had no problem with it on XP, my Notebook with w7 x64 pro and at the office with w7 x64 enterprise.
With my new home pc with w7 x64 pro the monitor goes off but instantly comes back on after a second.
So I tested using a power plan with the shortest timeout of 1 minute but with that the display never goes off at all.
(Setting a power plan timeout is no useful option because then I cannot read a document or watch a movie without the monitor going off)

I could try trial and error methods but this is cumbersome and not what I regard as a professional solution.
So I would prefer a way to analyze the windows events to find out the reason for the display staying active.

Add On:
In the meantime I tried safe mode and also exited from all tray programs but the problem is still there.
I also checked the BIOS for special power settings but still no solution (P.S. Mobo is H87-G41 PC Mate with latest BIOS rev.)

Comment: 1. The power button is a mechanical switch and those are not designed for frequent usage.  

2. The power button is more than an arm length away so it is much easier and ergonomic to press a key.  

3. The monitor stand is not so stable that pressing the power button doesn't twist the monitor.  

All in all I described a technical issue and as the problem is not with my other 3 machines there must be a reason why my Haswell system does not allow to power off the monitor even not through a windows power plan.

Comment: My two cents on this. I'm not sure if Windows can tell a monitor to turn off, rather it can tell him to become standby. Regardless, if you have a laser-based mouse, small readouts can and will take you out of inactivity.